# Getting base64 image from python server to set UIImage in swift

Tags: python, ios, socket.io, base64

I am using swift/socketio to upload an image to my python server.

### Send to Server

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let base64encoding = data?.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 3))
let result = client.send(string:base64encoding!)
```

The data is sent to the server as a base64 string. I then try to send it back to my xcode project and place it in a UIImage

### Python code

```
def connectionMade(self):
    self.factory.clients.append(self)
    print "a clinet connected ", self.factory.clients

def connectionLost(self, reason):
    self.factory.clients.remove(self)

def dataReceived(self, data):
    print data

"""Write back to user"""
self.transport.write(data)
```

### Send back to Client and Decode

```
guard let receivedMessage = client.read(1024*10) else {return}

if let response = String(bytes: receivedMessage, encoding:.utf8) {
    let decodedData = NSData(base64Encoded: response, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)


myImage.image = UIImage(data:decodedData! as Data)
myImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

My image is being set in the UIImage, but it is showing up pitch black. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Encoding :**

```
 let base64EnCodedStr:String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

**Decoding :**

```
 let decodedData:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64EnCodedStr, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)!
```